# Global assignment of list elements within a function, using a variable name for the list

Tags: r

The title is a bit loose. I would like to create a function that takes a list name as a variable, and assigns elements to that list. So far, I can access the list's elements via its name in the `my_fun` function. I can then modify the list within the function (using the function parameter), and `print` to verify that the assignment has worked. Of course, I'm not saving any of this to the global environment, so when I call the list outside of the function, it hasn't changed.

```
my_list <- list('original_element')

my_fun <- function(some_list) {

    # check that I can access the list using the parameter name
    print(some_list[[1]])

    # modify the list
    some_list[[1]] <- 'element_assigned_in_function'

    # check that the list was modified
    print(some_list[[1]]) 

}

my_fun(my_list)

# [1] "original_element"
# [1] "element_assigned_in_function"

# of course, my_list hasn't been modified in the global environment
my_list
# [[1]]
# [1] "original_element"
```

My question is, how could you assign new elements to this list within the function and store them in the global environment? If I simply try to make the assignment global with `<<-`, the following error is thrown:

> Error in some_list[[1]] <<- "element_assigned_in_function" : 
>     object 'some_list' not found

I've tried to use `assign` and set `envir = .GlobalEnv`, but that doesn't work and I don't think `assign` can be used with list elements. I suspect that there may be some quoting/unquoting/use of expressions to get this to work, but I haven't been able to figure it out. Thank you.

Comment: Change to `my_fun <- function(some_list) {
  some_list[[1]] <- 'element_assigned_in_function'; 
  some_list
}`

Comment: Why do you want to change the element in the global environment from inside the function? Can you return the element from the function as @Phil suggested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I'll be clear that I do not encourage assigning values to variables from inside the function in global environment. Ideally, you should always `return` the value from the function which you want to change. However, just for demonstration purpose here is a way in which you can change the contents of the list from inside the function

```
my_fun <- function(some_list) {
  list_name <- deparse(substitute(some_list))
  some_list[[1]] <- 'element_assigned_in_function'
  assign(list_name, some_list, .GlobalEnv)
}

my_list <- list('original_element')
my_fun(my_list)
my_list
#[[1]]
#[1] "element_assigned_in_function"
```